# I need help with cpp: cpp-7 issue

Tags: upgrade

I just did a clean install Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04 for my Dad and all went smooth until I got this message in terminal after running sudo apt-get update and upgrade. I'm bit lost as to how to resolve my issue.Any help is greatly appreciated. The old boy wants to fly his planes again. (80yr Vet RCAF). Thank you

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

cpp: cpp-7: Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) but 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
       Depends: libgmp10 (>= 2:5.0.1~) but 2:6.1.2+dfsg-2 is installed
       Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2 is installed
```

I just ran "apt policy cpp cpp-7" and here's the result. I still don't know what to do from here:

```
~$ apt policy cpp cpp-7
cpp:
  Installed: 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3
  Candidate: 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3
  Version table:
 *** 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
cpp-7:
  Installed: 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04
  Candidate: 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     7.3.0-30ubuntu1~18.04.york0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc-7.3/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.3.0-16ubuntu3 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: So you need to figure out why `cpp-7` isn't getting updated to 7.4.0 like the rest of the gcc-related stuff; perhaps start by posting the output of `apt policy cpp cpp-7`

Comment: Thanks, it's a long distance thing here so I will relay that command and repost the results when I receive them back. Much appreciated @steeldriver

Comment: @steeldriver Hi, I've added the results of "apt policy cpp cpp-7" above. Not sure what to do now. Dad is obviously running 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04

Comment: Thanks - so the most obvious oddity is the PPA (`http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc-7.3/ubuntu`) however that doesn't seem to be the version that's being selected - I'm not sure what to make of that

Comment: It also got my attention. I'm going to sleep on it and check back here tomorrow...thanks @steeldriver